# NotificationCompat.Builder shows a Dialog instead of notification

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I am working in a chat app, using push notifications with OneSignal.

If the user is in the app, but not in the conversation Activity, when a notification is received, a Dialog is drawn, instead a notification.

I want to show a notification, instead of a Dialog. This is the code:

```
protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult notification) {
    almacen=((Almacen)getApplication());
    JSONObject noti=notification.payload.additionalData;
    try {
        idChat=noti.getInt("idchat");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    showNoti=!(almacen.getIdChat()==idChat);
    if(showNoti){
        OverrideSettings overrideSettings = new OverrideSettings();
        overrideSettings.extender = new NotificationCompat.Extender() {
            @Override
            public NotificationCompat.Builder extend(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Almacen.getContext().getResources(),
                        R.drawable.chat);
                builder.setLargeIcon(icon);
                return builder.setColor(new BigInteger("FF0000FF", 16).intValue());
            }
        };

        OSNotificationDisplayedResult displayedResult = displayNotification(overrideSettings);
        Log.d("OneSignalExample", "Notification displayed with id: " + displayedResult.androidNotificationId);
    }else{
        if(almacen.getActivity()!=null){
            almacen.getActivity().reload();
        }
    }


    return true;
}
```

Using this, the app behaves like said: a Dialog is shown, not a notification.

How could I avoid that, and show a notification instead of Dialog?

Thank you.

Comment: `displayNotification(overrideSettings)` - what does this do?

Comment: Dunno, is a class from OneSignal.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, by adding this line:

```
.inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
```

In startInit method:

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new MyNotificationOpenedHandler())
            .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new MyNotificationReceivedHandler())
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .init();
```